# Map two types at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, mapping, template-meta-programming

I have a set of types related with a one-to-one relation, for example:

```
TypeA ---> Type1
TypeB ---> Type2 
TypeC ---> Type3
```

I know these relation at compile time.

Then, I have a template class that depends on this two types:

```
template<class T1,class T2>
class MyClass
{
  T1 foo;
  T2 bar;
};
```

Now, the user of my library will type something like:

```
MyClass<TypeA,Type1> x;
```

This is inconvenient because there is a dependency between the two types and it should be enough for the user specify only the first type.

Also, mixing the two types shouldn't be possible:

```
MyClass<TypeA,Type2> y; //it should not compile
```

I am not very familiar with template meta programming, I got the impression that this is doable task, but I may be wrong.

The number of types involved is big, however I am happy to run a script to generate the code if necessary.

Do you know if it is possible or I am wasting my time? Do you have any ideas to point me on the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct get_mapped;

template<>
struct get_mapped<TypeA>{
    typedef Type1 type;
};

// and so on....


template<class T>
class MyClass{
    typedef typename get_mapped<T>::type T2;

    T foo;
    T2 bar;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class T> struct TypeLetter2TypeDigit;

template<> struct TypeLetter2TypeDigit<TypeA> { typedef Type1 type; };
template<> struct TypeLetter2TypeDigit<TypeB> { typedef Type2 type; };
template<> struct TypeLetter2TypeDigit<TypeC> { typedef Type3 type; };


template<class T1>  // Type2 is not needed
class MyClass 
{ 
  // Type2 is deduced.
  typedef typename TypeLetter2TypeDigit<T1>::type T2;
  T1 foo; 
  T2 bar; 
};
```

Comment: Made some corrections. See if it's proper. (Also, do you really need such a long name `TypeLetter2TypeDigit` ? IMHO something like `TypeMap` is enough. )

Comment: @iammilind. Thank you. Long name is needed to show what I want. You or OP may use any name.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a wrapper type:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct wrapper
{
   typedef T1 type1;
   typedef T2 type2;
};

typedef wrapper<TypeA, Type1> TypeX;
typedef wrapper<TypeB, Type2> TypeY;
typedef wrapper<TypeC, Type3> TypeZ;
```

Then the user says, `MyClass<TypeX>;`, and you define:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
  typename T::type1 foo;
  typename T::type2 bar;
};
```

If you want to guard against misuse of the template, use a partial specialization:

```
template <typename> class MyClass; // undefined

template <typename S, typename T>
class MyClass<wrapper<S,T>>
{
  S foo;
  T bar;
};
```

This approach can easily be extended to include further compile-time data into the wrapper class. Alternatively, you could use `std::pair` with member types `first_type` and `second_type` instead.