# Is it possible to define a typedef on a template class via a template method?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Suppose I have a template class like so:

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeInformation {
    static int s_someArbitraryData;
}
template <typename T> TypeInformation<T>::s_someArbitraryData = 0;
```

Then, at some point later I can do something like this:

```
SomeFunction() {
    SetUpData<int>(); // Populates s_someArbitraryData for int.
}
```

By merely calling SetUpData I've set up one copy of s_someArbitraryData for the given type. What I would like to do, if possible, is to do a similar thing but set up a way to map types. Something like this, which doesn't currently work:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyTypeMap {}

// ...

SomeFunction() {
    SetUpTypemap<int, float>(); // Creates a typedef on MyTypeMap<int>
    MyTypeMap<int>::type myFloatValue = 1.0f; // A float value
}
```

I can accomplish this [right now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739946/63791) by having something like this:

```
template <>
struct MyTypeMap<int> {
    typedef float type;
}
```

But this has some annoying drawbacks for my situation. I suspect what I want isn't possible, but I also wouldn't be surprised if there's some deep template magic I am unaware of that can solve this.

Comment: Are you able to use C++11 or later? The `using` statement can give you a templated typedef.

Comment: I don't think you can do this (modifiable constexpr thing aside)

Comment: Isn't your first snippet wrong? What's `NameOfType`? Dis you mean `TypeInformation`?

Comment: @AndyG: C++11 is fine. I'll have to look into that. If you can post an example faster than I can figure out how to do it myself you can score the reputation :)

Comment: @skypjack: Yeah, my mistake. I change my example while writing it and didn't update it. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not so far from what you are looking for:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct tag { using type = T; };

template<typename...>
struct MapPart;

template<typename T, typename U, typename... O>
struct MapPart<T, U, O...>: MapPart<O...> {
    using MapPart<O...>::get;
    static constexpr tag<U> get(tag<T>) { return {}; }
};

template<>
struct MapPart<> {
    static constexpr void get();
};

template<typename... T>
struct Map: MapPart<T...> {
    template<typename U>
    using type = typename decltype(Map<T...>::template get<U>())::type;

    template<typename U>
    static constexpr auto get() {
        return MapPart<T...>::get(tag<U>{});
    }
};

int main() {
    using MyTypeMap = Map<int, float>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<MyTypeMap::type<int>, float>::value, "!");
    MyTypeMap::type<int> myFloatValue = 1.0f;
}
```

The final syntax is slightly different. You have this:

```
MyTypeMap::type<int>
```

Instead of this:

```
MyTypeMap<int>::type
```

Anyway, I think it's acceptable.

The type `MyTypeMap` is visible only in the scope of the using declaration. I assumed it was the intention of the original `SetUpTypemap<int, float>` function: set up the bind between `int` and `float` only within the function `SomeFunction`.

By using this approach you have the advantage of being able to set up more than one relationship at once.
As an example:

```
using MyTypeMap = Map<int, float, float, int>;

// ....

MyTypeMap::type<int> myFloatValue = 1.0f;
MyTypeMap::type<float> myIntValue = 1;
```

Also note that the first relationship set for a type is the strongest one.
In other terms, if you do this:

```
using MyTypeMap = Map<int, float, int, char>;
```

The type `MyTypeMap::type<int>` will be `float` and it will hide the relationship between `int` and `char`.

Not a perfect solution, but maybe a working one that solves your issue.